# Как изменить расстояния padding и margin элементов (иконок) в меню?

Tags: android

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как изменить расстояния (padding и margin) элементов в меню? Мне необходимо их уменьшить т.к. стандартные расстояния великоваты для приложения.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Меню создаю так:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<item android:id="@+id/menu_contents"
    android:title="@string/menu_contents"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_format_list_numbered"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    app:showAsAction="always" />

<item android:id="@+id/menu_search"
    android:title="@string/menu_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

Заполняю стандартным методом:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
return true;
}
```

UPD 1:
Мой главный стиль выглядит так:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverFlow</item>
```

Answer (score 5):

Можно попробовать так в styles.xml, по умолчанию minWidth = 56dip

```
  <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/MyActionButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:maxWidth">30dip</item>
</style>
```

или так

```
  <style name="MyActionButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:minWidth">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">0dip</item>
</style>
```

Для того, чтобы это работало на версии Android 17+ нужно добавить в res/values-v17/styles.xml

```
<style name="MyActionButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:minWidth">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingStart">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingEnd">0dip</item>
</style>
```

Comment: почему-то не работает (запускал на API 19). Добавил свой главный стиль в вопрос.

Пробовал все ваши варианты. Может быть я что-то делаю неправильно?